# Is the empty string a subset or element of all alphabets?

Tags: set, theory, set-theory

I'm having trouble understanding when the empty string (epsilon) is a subset or element of an alphabet?  My understanding was that epsilon was only part of a language, but my TA in the class said it was an element of all alphabets so now I am confused.

```
e.g. would {a,b,c} contain epsilon as an element?
e.g. would {} contain epsilon as an element?
e.g. is {eps} a subset of all alphabets or languages?
```

Comment: I posted an answer for you. Did it help answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

This question is probably better suited for [cs.stackexchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) but I will try to help you according to my understanding, please do correct me if necessary.

In general, your own intuition seems quite correct to me. *ϵ* is **not** automatically part of every alphabet. It is the empty string of characters.

However, this means that *ϵ* is a string **over any alphabet**, even your alphabet *{a, b, c}*.

So to answer your three examples:

1. No, it does not. If *{a, b, c}* is an alphabet, it is a set of symbols, and *ϵ* is a string. However, *ϵ* is definitely part of some languages defined over this alphabet.
2. No, *{}* is the empty set, and it contains nothing, not even *ϵ*.
3. *{ϵ}* is the set containing only *ϵ*. *ϵ* is a string, not a symbol, so it is not a subset of all alphabets (however, it seems there are cases where some alphabets are defined to contain *ϵ* but that is a different confusing story). It is also not a subset of all languages, because consider the language *L = {aa, ab, ba, bb}*. The empty string *∈* is not one of these elements.

The analogue to set theory might cause some additional confusion. Notice that the empty set is a subset of every set. The empty string is not a subset of every language, but rather it is a **substring** of any string.